# Running multiple SQL statements from Groovy

Tags: mysql, groovy

I'm having problems running multiple SQL statements in one activaction from Groovy.

```
sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost/", "usre", "pass", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
sql.execute("USE foo; "); // this works
sql.execute("USE foo; USE foo;"); // this fails miserably
```

The error I'm getting is "You have an error in your SQL syntax". What gives?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024490/soapui-groovy-scripts-executing-multiple-sql-statements-in-one-go

Comment: @ajreal - I'll the workaround ... but why the *** does this happen? Created issue - http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4540

Comment: @ajreal - that doesn't work. I'd like to use the `use` statement, followed by a set of statements. I could parse the SQL, and add the schema prefix to each of the statements, but I'd rather they just wait for them fix the bug, assuming it will happen soon.

Comment: I guess groovy does not support multiple query for mysql yet, such as php only has support for multiple query for mysqli instead of the older mysql. You can consider to wrap multiple queries into stored procedure or a function

Comment: @ajreal - I prefer my solution (see below)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply augment the following jdbc url parameter to your connection string

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html#allowMultiQueries

From the docs:

> Allow the use of ';' to delimit
>   multiple queries during one statement
>   (true/false), defaults to 'false'

For example:

```
Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost?allowMultiQueries=true", "usre", "pass", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because groovy uses JDBC's Statement.execute(), which expects on statement. Here is a replacement class for Groovy's Sql that works around this problem (but lacks in functionality)

```
/**
 * Not related to mysql, just to distinguish it from Groovy's Sql class
 * Created to solve this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286483/running-multiple-sql-statements-from-groovy
 */
public class MySql {
  private final String password;
  private final String connectionString;
  private final String user;

  public static newInstance(String connectionString, String user, String password, String driverName) {
    Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
    return new MySql(connectionString, user, password);
  }

  public MySql(String connectionString, String user, String password) {
    this.connectionString = connectionString;
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;
  }

  void execute(String query) {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, user, password);
    try {
      Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
      for (String subQuery : query.split(";"))
      {
        if (subQuery.trim() == '')
          continue;

        statement.addBatch subQuery
      }
      statement.executeBatch();
    }
    finally {
      conn.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work if you have semicolons as data in some text field.

Answer (score 0):

Paul King, one of the Groovy developers, commented on the issue I opened that you can tell mysql to allow multiple statements (this is not necessarily supported by other RDBMS)