# Groovy: using switch/case with mysql queries

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a TEXT file:

```
ACTION = NEW        
NEW_NUMBER = '123456'
TEXT_NAME1 = 'TEST1'
TEXT_NAME2 = 'TEST2'
TEXT_NAME3 = 'TEST3'
```

and I want make multiple INSERT queries in my code. How I can do that?

```
def sqlstr = new Properties().with { props ->
  new File( '/path/to/file' ).withReader { r ->
    load( r )
    switch( props.ACTION ) {
      case 'NEW':
        "INSERT INTO TABLE1.DB (NUMBER, NAME1, NAME2, NAME3) VALUES ($NEW_NUMBER, $TEXT_NAME1, $TEXT_NAME2, $TEXT_NAME3)"
        "INSERT INTO TABLE2.DB (NUMBER, NAME1, NAME2, NAME3) VALUES ($NEW_NUMBER, $TEXT_NAME1, $TEXT_NAME2, $TEXT_NAME3)" 
        break

    }
  }
}

// Assuming sql is set up right:
sql.execute sqlstr
```

Comment: and the problem is?......

Comment: script not work with 2 inserts.

Comment: how about adding `;` on every statement? what error does it throw?

Comment: no errors. just sql.execute cannot execute 2 INSERTs in one query and dont create numbers in tables in database. if i remove one insert - script is work

Comment: See [Running multiple SQL statements from Groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286483/running-multiple-sql-statements-from-groovy)