# Multiple SQL statements using Groovy

Tags: sql, jdbc, groovy, soapui

Delete multiple entries from DB using Groovy in SoapUI

I am able to execute one SQL statement, but when I do a few it just hangs.

How can I delete multiple rows?

```
  def sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:oracle:thin:@jack:1521:test1', 'test', 'test', 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver')
    log.info("SQL connetced")
  sql.connection.autoCommit = false

  try {
log.info("inside try")
  log.info("before")
  String Que =
  """delete from table name where user in (select user  from user where ID=    '123' and type= 262);
 delete from table name where user in (select user  from user where ID= '1012' and type= 28)
 delete from table name where user in (select user  from user where ID= '423' and type= 27)
"""
  log.info (Que)
 def output = sql.execute(Que);

   log.info(sql)

               log.info(output)
     log.info("after")

     sql.commit()
     println("Successfully committed")

  }catch(Exception ex) {
     sql.rollback()
     log.info("Transaction rollback"+ex)
  }

  sql.close()
```

Comment: also to note. when i run these delete statements from sql developer direct. no issues. no lag and takes just under 10 seconds..

Comment: Please check the answer and see if that helps.

Comment: JDBC is statement oriented, so you can only execute a single statement at a time.

Comment: I didn't try it, but I think the second and last SQL statements are just missing the semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for.

I feel it is more effective way if you want bulk number of records using the following way.

- Create a map for the data i.e., id, type as key value pair that needs to be removed in your case.
- Used closure to execute the query by iterating thru it.

Added comments appropriately.

```groovy
//Closure to execute the query with parameters
def runQuery = { entry ->
    def output = sql.execute("delete from table name where user in (select user  from user where ID=:id and type=:type)", [id:entry.key, type:entry.value] )
    log.info(output)    
}

//Added below two statements
//Create the data that you want to remove in the form of map id, and type
def deleteData = ['123':26, '1012':28, '423':27]

def sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:oracle:thin:@jack:1521:test1', 'test', 'test', 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver')
log.info("SQL connetced")
sql.connection.autoCommit = false
try {
    log.info(sql)
    log.info("inside try")
    log.info("before")
    //Added below two statements
    //Call the above closure and pass key value pair in each iteration
    deleteData.each { runQuery(it) }
    log.info("after")

    sql.commit()
    println("Successfully committed")

}catch(Exception ex) {
    sql.rollback()
    log.info("Transaction rollback"+ex)
}

sql.close()
```

If you are just looking after execution of multiple queries only approach, then you may look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024490/soapui-groovy-scripts-executing-multiple-sql-statements-in-one-go) and not sure if your database supports the same.